# An Arduino can be reprogrammed any number of times. But I have read that it is FPGAs that are reprogrammable. Is an Arduino an FPGA?

Tags: microcontroller, fpga, embedded

I know that the Arduino boards use MCUs.

But when searching through the differences between MCUs and FPGAs, I read again and again that FPGAs are reprogrammable while MCUs are not.
The first example that came to my mind was the Arduino.

Can somebody clarify the difference between MCUs and FPGAs, and when to use which?

Comment: Technically an FPGA is not reprogrammable since it does not run a program. An FPGA is reconfigurable. An Arduino on the other hand, does run a program. That should be enough to tell you that an Arduino (which is an MCU) is not an FPGA.

Comment: "Any number of times" is a bit of an exaggeration. The guaranteed number of erase/write cycles for the flash in the ATMega328p is 10,000 so you can easily easy wear it out in short order if you want to.

Comment: Welcome to the site. This is a few lines that asks for mountains of effort in reply. The site is not for free personal tutoring and you can quite easily research this on the internet. There is a tremendous amount of information there already written on this, freely available to beginners and experienced engineers alike. Such research is part of how the former become the latter. This has led to the question being closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FPGAs and Arduinos are both "reprogrammable" (in a loose sense of the term), but at different level of abstraction. The proper term for an FPGA (as raised by a comment to the question) is that an FPGA is re*configurable*.

A microcontroller (i.e. the key part of an Arduino) is distinctly not an FPGA -- if you compare the kind of process for programming each (e.g. writing C or C++ and compiling it to AVR assembly, vs writing an HDL and going through synthesis + place-and-route to a bitstream) you'll see a number of ways in which the two are vastly dissimilar devices. In brief, you'll see that for an Arduino, you write procedural code, which is compiled to a sequential series of assembly instructions, indicating the steps that the microcontroller should do.

On the other hand, when targeting an FPGA, you are not describing a sequence of steps to be taken by a CPU, rather you are describing *hardware*, and consequently you use a *hardware description language* (HDL) and skills+techniques from digital electronics and hardware design courses, rather than pure software approaches. When this design is converted from HDL to a machine-readable format uploaded to the chip, it's not compiled into a set of sequential assembly instructions, but rather *synthesized* to a netlist and then further converted to a bitstream. This bitstream describes *hardware* that is instantiated within the programmable logic elements of the FPGA itself (mostly lookup tables, registers, and interconnect along with some hardwired functions like adder carry chains, multipliers, block RAM, and transceivers).

The beauty of the FPGA approach is parallelism - if I want an Arduino to decode data from a serial port and also drive a motor controller, I2C based sensor, and a flash chip, I need to do one at a time. The program will spend time on one of these tasks and switch to another (e.g. using an interrupt, by doing them all in a loop, or even using an RTOS). On the other hand, an FPGA can have a motor controller driver, a UART, an I2C interface with a state machine to drive it, and a flash chip interface all programmed and acting at the same time, on the same clock signal. This of course comes with cost and complexity.

This, of course, comes at an equivalent counter-argument -- an FPGA is not efficient when you need to do a vast variety of distinct tasks, one-at-a-time. Each of those tasks requires space in the FPGA's fabric to fit its logic, while the logic for all but one of those tasks sits idle. An MCU can easily branch to distinct areas of code memory, or even load code from larger memories depending on the architecture. There are tricks like using partial reconfiguration or an MCU that loads different bitstreams for different tasks onto an FPGA, but they present their own sets of complexity/latency. Partial reconfiguration is difficult and requires special licensing+tooling, and reloading bitstreams takes a few seconds, making it only useful when such downtime between tasks is OK.

There's one other interesting caveat here, which is that an MCU is nothing more than a pile of digital logic (i.e. an ALU, some registers, a memory interface, and a bus for special function units). If my FPGA is big enough, I can use an HDL to implement a processor to a spec of my choosing -- I could potentially even make it run the same assembly as an Arduino, addressing the same space of memory, with a comparable (or even higher) clock speed. I can also integrate special function units of my own choosing (since again, they are just logic) as long as the FPGA is large enough to fit that logic. Of course, it will require more electrical power, a more complex board layout, and cost more than an MCU.

Comment: !   Thank you so much for the beautiful explanation.

Comment: Although parallelism and power consumption were also the differences I have read about, but your last para cleared the air for me in a way no one else could. So basically, an FPGA can be reconfigured at a hardware level to get whatever configuration we want(or else we can change MCU and place a new one each time we want the core configuration to be changed ).

Comment: Which brings me to my next question . For that to happen, I think the PCBs will have to be designed differently(in case of FPGAs) ? I may be wrong , again, but , I think the pins of FPGAs on PCBs will have to be very generalised ? For example, a FPGA GPIO pin may be reconfigured in future to connect to an oscillator ?

Comment: @JalajChaturvedi FPGAs generally have dedicated pins for oscillator connections. Unlike a "normal" IOB, the clock pins have direct, low-jitter, high-speed connections directly to clock buffers, PLLs, MMCMs, etc which drive fast, low-jitter, balanced clock spines in the fabric. On the other hand, a normal IOB goes straight to "standard" routing which is good for data signals but not great for clocks. I already alluded to other PCB differences, such as an FPGA often requiring more power supply rails, more decoupling.